# WSO2 API Manager (1.6.0): Publisher API (endpoints)

Tags: json, api, wso2, endpoint

When using the published API for the publisher has been changed for the endpoints. According to: http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Publisher+APIs#PublisherAPIs-AddUpdateAPI

> From APIM 1.6.0 this service accepts endpoint configuration data as a
>   JSON value. In endpoint config JSON you have to specify
>   "endpoint_type" and "production_endpoints" and/or "sandbox_endpoints".

We configure the endpoint as

```
endpoint_config={"production_endpoints":{"url":"http://my.backend.server/HelloWorldService","config":null},"endpoint_type":"http"}
```

But what is the syntax if I want to define a WSDL endpoint? And how do I configure basic authentication in the API (username,password)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the endpoint config in the following manner:

```
endpoint_config={"production_endpoints":{"url":"http://localhost:9763/services/HelloService?wsdl","config":null},"wsdlendpointService":"http://localhost:9763/services/HelloService","wsdlendpointPort":"http://localhost:9763/services/HelloService.HelloServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint","endpoint_type":"wsdl"}
```

Basically you need to provide the WSDL, Service URL and the port type as a JSON.

When do you mean configuring Basic Authentication are you trying to access a Backend Secured with Basic Authentication or are you trying to secure the API using Basic Authentication?

Comment: My endpoint on the backend server is secured with username and password. How do I pass this in this config?

Comment: If you click show more options under the Endpoint section, it'll reveal another field Endpoint Security Scheme. By default this is set to Non Secured. If you select Secured option, it'll show two additional text boxes to provide the username and the password of the backend server.

Comment: I saw it in the console, but what is the syntax in the endpoint_config?

Comment: You can pass these parameters endpointType=secured&epUsername=username&epPassword=userpass